# How to add active style using bootstrap

Tags: c#, css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

good day, i'm trying to add an active style to indicate current page on my web app bt couldn't get a solution, i looked at previous post and answers where i saw this which was said to have worked

```
<ul class="nav">
 <li><a data-target="#" data-toggle="pill" href="#accounts">Accounts</a></li>
 <li><a data-target="#" data-toggle="pill" href="#users">Users</a></li><br/> 
</ul>
```

when i used the data-toggle attribute in this code

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="colour">@Html.ActionLink("Staffs", "addStaff", "SchlAdmin")</li>
            <li class="colour" data-toggle="tab">@Html.ActionLink("Students", "addStudent", "SchlAdmin")</li>
            <li class="colour">@Html.ActionLink("Incidents", "staffInc", "SchlAdmin")</li>
            <li class="colour" data-toggle="tab">@Html.ActionLink("Admin", "addasset", "SchlAdmin")</li>
            <li class="colour">@Html.ActionLink("Search", "staffSearch", "SchlAdmin")</li>
            <li class="colour" data-toggle="tab">@Html.ActionLink("Profile", "prof", "SchlAdmin")</li>
        </ul>
```

i couldn't redirect to the page that has the data-toggle attribute but made that page active.

Answer (score 2):

I have already made the same issue. Please see my Code and I think it helps you, if you have some question I'm ready to answer you.

**View:**

```
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
                <li id="activeTab" class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#active">Active</a></li>
                <li id="currentTab" class=""><a data-toggle="tab" href="#current">Current</a></li>
                <li id="completedTab" class=""><a data-toggle="tab" href="#completed">Completed</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
                <div id="active" class="tab-pane fade active in">
                    @Html.Action("Active", "Home")
                </div>
                <div id="current" class="tab-pane fade">
                    @Html.Action("Current", "Home")
                </div>
                <div id="completed" class="tab-pane fade in">
                    @Html.Action("Completed","Home")
                </div>
            </div>
```

**JavaScript - when need to catch Active tab from URL and make it open**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var tab = @ViewBag.tabId;
        switch (tab) {
        case 1:
            removeAllActiveTabs();
            $('#activeTab').addClass('active');
            $('#active').addClass('active');
            $('#active').addClass('in');
            break;
        case 2:
            removeAllActiveTabs();
            $('#currentTab').addClass('active');
            $('#current').addClass('active');
            $('#current').addClass('in');
            break;
        case 3:
            removeAllActiveTabs();
            $('#completedTab').addClass('active');
            $('#completed').addClass('active');
            $('#completed').addClass('in');
            break;
        default:
            $('#activeTab').addClass('active');
            $('#active').addClass('active');
            $('#active').addClass('in');
            break;
        }
    });

    function removeAllActiveTabs() {
        $('#myTab').each(function() {
            $(this).find('li').removeClass('active');
        });
        $('#myTabContent').each(function() {
            $(this).find('div').removeClass('active');
            $(this).find('div').removeClass('in');
        });
    }
```

**JavaScript - If you want to change URL when tab change**

```
   //When Client click on Tabs show in URL
    $('#activeTab').on('click',function() {
        window.history.pushState('','','/Home/SomeAction?tabId=1');
    });
    $('#currentTab').on('click',function() {
        window.history.pushState('','','/Home/SomeAction?tabId=2');
    });
    $('#completedTab').on('click',function() {
        window.history.pushState('','','/Home/SomeAction?tabId=3');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a classname active to your li.
Example:

```
<li class="active"><a data-target="#" data-toggle="pill" href="#users">Users</a></li>
```

Comment: adding a class name active to a particular li element only makes that class active, as i switch tabs, that class still remain active